# Java "resource"-folder changes to usual folder by itself sometimes?

Tags: java, properties, directory

I'm using Java "Properties"-Class and method "getClass().getResourceAsStream()" in order to retrieve constants stored in an external text file.

I noticed that whenever I close my IDE (Eclipse) and reopen it, my created folder "resources" (**File -> New -> Source Folder**) does not appear as a "source folder" anymore, but as a normal, ordinary folder. As a result, my program cannot find the file with the constants anymore that is stored in this folder, because the file with the constants is required to be stored in a definite "Source Folder".

Does anybody know or can explain why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have deleted your .classpath file from the project folder for some reason.

Check what's in your .classpath file. It's under your Java project folder. This file is where Eclipse stores the class path information and it manages it for you. I added a screenshot for what I got in my TestProject folder and what .classpath file contains.

If your resource folder is not listed there as a source folder, you can always add it back by going into right click menu of the project in Eclipse, and then select Build Path -> Config Build Path.

If restarting of Eclipse will cause it to fail to read the .classpath, it might be Eclipse's issue or your .classpath is gone somehow.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it actually was the .classpath file that was gone and caused the problems. Problem solved, thanks a lot!